# Как будет происходить инициализация value type на низком уровне?

Tags: память, компилятор

возник вопрос, как работает память с value type на низком уровне.
Допустим мы создаем переменную
`var first = 5`
Получается, что в стеке у нас будет храниться значение, а в коде адрес на место в стеке (смещение).
Объявим вторую переменную
`var second = first`
Как будет происходить инициализация на низком уровне? Перейдем по смещению в стеке и возьмем значение?
Если допустил какие-то ошибки - прошу поправить. Также буду благодарен, если подбросите книгу/статью на эту тему

Comment: В каком языке программирования? Разные языки могут делать по-разному

Comment: Хотелось бы на примере Swift, но можно и на С

Comment: Зайдите на сайт https://gcc.godbolt.org и увидите сразу.

Comment: К сожалению не владею знаниям такими, чтобы понимать код справа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В целом Вы правильно понимаете как это будет работать. Компилятор знает количество и размер всех локальных переменных. Для каждой переменной он определит её смещение в стековом кадре. После этого компилятор будет оперировать уже не обращением к объекту, а смещением на стеке. В начале процедуры будут созданы операции, записывающие в адрес локальной переменной начальное значение. В некоторых случаях компилятор может посчитать что для переменной достаточно выделить регистр чтобы не работать с оперативной памятью. Почитать про это можно в любом учебнике по компиляторам.